# How can I change the color of angularjs spinners

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm currently working on angularjs application and have integrated angularjs spinner. I have also successfully overridden some of angularjs spin-kit css to make the spinner that I'm using to appear and display the way I want but unable to change the color of the spinners. I want to be able to change the color of the spinners so that it blends with the colors on my app.

Comment: You can view these spinners on jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Urigo/638AA/18/

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/tobiasahlin/SpinKit/tree/master/scss/spinners
You have to do something similar to override colors.

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/f0np09Lj/1/

Comment: Yes @Deep but if I apply css rule of  'background-color', the background gets changed but not the spinner itself

Comment: which spinner? @Deep solution seems quite good

Comment: The 'fading-circle-spinner' @sexta13

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the fading-circle-spinner color specifically then you can use this css class

```
.fading-circle:before{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Joffutt. it worked....finding this class was my problem. I'm grateful guys..